# Ошибка: IntegrityError at / UNIQUE constraint failed: registration_choose.id

Tags: python, django

Делаю сайт на джанго. Я делаю голосование и хочу, чтобы в бд попадал проголосовавший пользователь, для чего пишу `voter.request.user`. Но из-за этого возникает эта ошибка. Как мне ее исправить?

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: registration_choose.id
[28/Dec/2021 20:11:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 178087
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    value, created = Choose.objects.get_or_create(voter=request.user, pk=1)
    context = {
        "value": value,
    }

return render(request, 'registration/home.html', context)



def black(request):
    value, created = Choose.objects.get_or_create(voter=request.user, pk=1)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        select_action = request.POST['choose']

        if select_action == 'black':
            value.count_black += 1
            value.save()
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/black.html', {"value": value})

        return redirect("home")


    context = {"value": value}
    return render(request, 'registration/black.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Choose(models.Model):
    count_black = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="black")
    count_white = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="white")
    count_purple = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="purple")
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, verbose_name='Пользователь', 
    on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `.get_or_create()` возвращает объект, если он удовлетворяет условиям поиска. Иначе, он создаёт новый объект с переданными в него аргументами.

Судя по всему, в вашей БД уже есть один объект `Choose` c `pk=1`, но его `voter` при вызове функции отличается, поэтому Джанго пытается создать объект с `pk=1` и `voter=reqeust.user`. Но так как `pk` является уникальным полем, что значит, что в базе не может быть два объекта с одним `pk` , он выкидывает такую ошибку.

На мой взгляд, чтобы исправить эту ошибку, достаточно убрать аргумент `pk`.

Comment: спасибо вам, это помогло.